# How to account for VFS operations at the block device layer?

Tags: vfs, ebpf

I want to measure how much could be gained by placing some of a filesystem data on a fast device, vs regular spinning disks. As an example, measure extended attribute (xattr) operations, vs regular reads and writes.

I started with the "bpftrace" tool, following individual VFS calls with a thread local variable.
Attempting to catch the associated block device requests fails, probably because the actual IO is done by a "kworker" process.

Here is the naive code:

```
kprobe:vfs_getxattr,
kprobe:vfs_setxattr,
kprobe:vfs_read*,
kprobe:vfs_write*
/comm == "some-process"/
{
    @start[tid] = nsecs;
    @name[tid] = func;
}

tracepoint:block:block_rq_issue
/@start[tid]/
{
    @bio[@name[tid]] = count();
}

kretprobe:vfs_getxattr,
kretprobe:vfs_setxattr,
kretprobe:vfs_read*,
kretprobe:vfs_write*
/@start[tid]/
{
    @count[@name[tid]] = count();
    delete(@start[tid]);
    delete(@name[tid]);
}
```

Is there any way I could follow the VFS calls down to block device IO?

Answer (score 0):

there are two options

1. use [blktrace](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blktrace)
2. Part of bcc specifically [biosnoop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/eb32c1587fd5f4186e7dcc4597326c42e476528e/tools/biosnoop.py)  Trace block device I/O and print details including issuing PID.

Maybe helpful 
here is Brendan Greg's blog post. I refer for using eBPF.

[Linux Performance](http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html)